# How can I map all of the context paths to one web application in Jetty?

Tags: jetty

I have created a web application and deploy it as `ROOT.war` to /webapps folder in Jetty. The RESTful interface can be triggered correctly when I browse http://SERVER_IP:8080/, but not in the case of http://SERVER_IP:8080/abc. I think Jetty attempts to find `abc.war` for the request http://SERVER_IP:8080/abc but failed. How can I configure Jetty to let it know that my web application is the one and only one application on it, and it should send all of the request to my web application no matter what URL is requested?

Many thanks!